# How to use postgres intervals in go?

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I have a go project that connects to a postgres database.  I want to delete orders over a certain number of days - I have tried doing it like this:

```
type SQLOrderDatabase struct {
    Connection *pgx.Conn
    logger     *logrus.Entry
}



interval := pgtype.Interval{}

_ = interval.Set(time.Second * 5)
_, err := database.Connection.Exec(ctx, "DELETE FROM store.items WHERE store.time > (now() AT TIME ZONE 'utc' - $1);", &interval)
```

This is using the pgx library and pgx types.  However it consistently fails with this error:

```
Error:ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone \u003e interval (SQLSTATE 42883)","severity":"error","
```

Is there anyway to use postgres intervals with go?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough context for postgres to know how you want to subtract the data passed as `$1` so you need to explicitly tell it, which you can do by [type casting](https://postgresql.org/docs/13/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) the parameter.

```sql
(now() AT TIME ZONE 'utc' - $1::interval)
```